# NodeJS API 401 Unauthorized

Tags: reactjs, express

I have Express API in DomainA.com(digital ocean) and the website is DomainB.com(Firebase Hosting).

I am able to login successfully from DomainB.com by calling the DomainA.com API - router.post('/user/login', async (req, res) => {...}

But when I try to access product API, I get 401 (Unauthorized)

This is DomainB.com API:

```
router.post('/product/allproducts', UserJWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {..}
```

This is DomainA.com call the API:

```
 const response = await Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_URL + '/api/product/allproducts',{id:productid.id,skipcnt:3}, {withCredentials:true})
```

I did a localhost test and it is all working fine.

I am wondering where did I get it wrong? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Comment: did u check the network tab what are the headers u sent? u sure jwt was sent? What happens when u remove UserJWTAuthenticatToken middleware?

Comment: Thanks, I did remove the JWT and it works. But the things is that, the JWT middleware and token generation and JWT validation are done at DomainB.com. I am not sure what am I suppose to take note on DomainA.com headers. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: If you can't debug with all your codes, I cannot advise base on the 2 lines of codes either... I suspect it got to do with cookies on your firebase function, you should first diagnose whether you are seeing the cookie

Comment: AND..if you are using cookie, and since it's different domain, cookie won't work, you cannot set domainA cookie from domainB, so there's no cookie, so there's no JWT token, so you will get 403. You can share subdomain like subdomain1.domain.com and subdomain2.domain.com and set cookie as .domain.com

Comment: hi Someone Special, Thanks and you are right that I am using cookie and yes you are right again that cookie won't work across 2 domains. I greatly appreciate your replies and once again thanks.